# How to uncheck all checkboxes when modal is closed in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

So I have angular 8 application.

And I have some checkboxes. I have also a button that triggers a other component(dialog) where you can make a selection on some data. but if the dialog close than the checkboxes has to be unchecked.

So this is the template with checkbox:

list.component

```
  <mat-checkbox
            (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
            (change)="$event ? onCheckboxChange($event, row) : null"
            [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
          >
          </mat-checkbox>
```

list.ts:

```
 selection = new SelectionModel<ParticipantInfoDTO>(true, []);

onCheckboxChange(event, row) {
    const isChecked = event.checked;
    const particpantId = row.participantId;
    if (isChecked) {
      this.participantIds.push(particpantId);
    } else {
      this.participantIds = this.participantIds.filter(id => id !== particpantId);
    }
    this.selection.toggle(row);
    this.selectedParticipantsService.updateParticipantIdsList(this.participantIds);
  }
```

and this is the other component:

EcheqSelectorComponent.ts:

```
 .subscribe(
          () => {
            this.dialog.close();
          //So what I have to fill in here so that all the checkboxes in the list.component will be unchecked



            this.snackBar.open('De vcheq(s) zijn verstuurd', 'Ok');
          },
          error => {
            console.error('Server error when assigning vcheq', error);
            this.snackBar.open('Er ging iets mis bij het opsturen, probeer het later nog een keer', 'Ok');
            this.dialog.close();
          }
        );
```

So what I have to change, to uncheck checkboxes when modal is closed?

Thank you

So this is the data in component list.ts:

```
const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
```

That I have to use in the component eceq-selector.

But how to to do that?

So I try it like this:

in echeq-selector:

```
 constructor(
    @Inject(ListComponent)
    private listComponent: ListComponent,
}
```

and then like this:

```
 this.listComponent.selection.clear();
```

But then I get this error:

```
core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EcheqSelectorComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Material Dialogs, you have the `dialog.afterClosed()` method that you can hook into when your dialog closes.  This gives you the power to unsubscribe from stuff, clear forms and do whatever you'd like.  It's pretty awesome, here's a link so you can see exactly how to use it as well as all that you can do with it.

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

I use it like crazy in my projects for clearing forms, resetting state and all kinds of awesomeness.